# ag-grid visual Upgrade: Checkerboard Patterns in Ag-Grid for Minimal Data Display

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-table, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-Grid, a JavaScript data grid library.

**Problem** : I have a problem with the grid when there is not enough data. 
When the grid has more than 20 rows of data, the grid is large enough to display all of the data, so there is no problem.
**However**, when the grid has 10 rows of data or less, the grid is not large enough to display all of the data. As a result, the remaining part of the grid is blank.

**My goal** : paint blank spot with check board

this image might you understand better
[image]

[image]

I would like to make the blank part of the grid have a checkerboard pattern when the grid has 10 rows of data or less. This way, the grid will still be visually appealing even when there is not enough data to fill it."

Here is a more concise version:

"When the Ag-Grid data grid has 10 or fewer rows, the remaining part of the grid is blank. I would like to add a checkerboard pattern to this blank area

this image down below is my end up goal
[image]

Comment: you could try adding empty rows which would achieve the same effect?

Comment: @ViqMontana do you mean If there are only two displayed data sets, add dummy data be generated to fill the screen with n more sets